# TaskListener not invoked in unit test based on ActivitiRule

Tags: junit, activiti

I am making use of ActivitiRule in unit test for process definition.

I have implemented a TaskListener in the flow.

But during test execution, TaskListener doesn't get invoked at all.

Do I need to do anything extra in unit test?

Comment: can you show your bpmn xml?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the fully qualified name of the listener and the event type are correctly specified in the xml file

In general, listeners are written like this in an XML file

```
<extensionElements>
    <activiti:executionListener event="start" class="test.activiti.listener.NewExecutionListener"/>
    <activiti:executionListener event="end" class="test.activiti.listener.NewExecutionListener"/>
</extensionElements>
```